# Azure emulator ports different

Tags: wcf, azure

When I run my WCF in normal mode it works, but when I run through the Azure Computer Emulator on my local PC, the port numbers are different. For instance, the WCF page opens up in under the address: `http://localhost:81/ServiceName1.svc`, but the WSDL address says

You can also access the service description as a single file:

`http://pc-name1:82/ServiceName1.svc?singleWsdl`

When I try to connect using WCF test client, it is not working when I try to fetch the address `http://localhost:81/ServiceName1.svc` or the address `http://pc-name1:82/ServiceName1.svc`

Do you know what might be happening? Has anyone noticed this when using the Azure emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through the [Hosting WCF within Windows Azure exercise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_azurefromsponpremusingjquery_topic2.aspx)? This behaviour is explained. You need an update to the WCF - KB981002- WCF: Hotfix rollup update, which will add a special behavior for your WCF services:

> 7.About the System.ServiceModel configuration above:
>
> 1. For this example we are exposing a metadata exchange (MEX) endpoint in addition to the service main endpoint. This will expose
>      the service metadata and thus allow service references to be added to
>      this service in Visual Studio.
> 2. The useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress behavior is a special behavior that is defined in KB981002- WCF: Hotfix rollup update. It
>      allows WCF to serve correct metadata behind load balancers. Windows
>      Azure web roles are load balanced between one or more physical
>      servers.